# jQuery css3 background-size

Tags: jquery

I have problems using jQuery `.css('background-size','contain');`

On Google Chrome sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.. (90% of cases it doesn't work)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function scaleImg(){    

    var img = $('#img_src_div img');
    if(img.height() >= 600 || img.width() >= 570){
        $('#img_src_div').css('background-size','contain');
    }

}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uAKLA/1/), and it is working. But inside my page it is not.
And it's pretty much the same, there is some php generated content, like urls and some text. and the code it's inside a parent div.

I tried removing all javascripts that may interfer with it, but it's the same. In firefox it's all ok.

EDIT:

images.php - This it's included on another php page.

```
//Removed - Was not usefull.
```

**2nd EDIT**:  By calling `scaleImg();` manually after the page is loaded, the background get scaled. So there is a issue on the page load..

This is the exact code i'm using right now.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function scaleImg() {
    var container = document.getElementById(\'img_src_div\');
    var img = container.children[0]; // assuming image is first child
    // var img = container.getElementsByTagName(\'img\')[0]; // use this one if not
    if( img.width >= 570 || img.height >= 600) container.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
    scaleImg();
    });
    </script>
```

**3rd and last (hopefully) EDIT:**

I've solved, the problem was that `$(document).ready(...);` it's executed before the image has been fully downloaded. So instead to call `scaleImg();` on document ready function, i call it inside `onload=""` of the image tag.

```
<img alt="" onload="scaleImg(this.width,this.height);" id="img_src" src="image_url" />
```

Comment: Unless this is a known bug in Chrome, we'd need to see something from the broken scenario to help.

Comment: The scaling it is not working, the Background Image it's loaded on full size.

Comment: @isherwood The strange thing it's that inside the JSFiddle example it's working, so i don't think can be a Chrome bug. I will edit my post and add the main page.

Comment: @doniyor Of Course i have it. In firefox it's working! Only chrome has issue.

Comment: @DjRikyx, look, check for any typo. e.g. ``;`` . in ff, this doesnot give error, but in chrome.. take a look here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-not-working-for-me-in-chrome

Comment: @doniyor I will check that, thank you.

Comment: I've checked the css, also used the WC3 validator. And it's all ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try plain JavaScript:

```
function scaleImg() {
    var container = document.getElementById('img_src_div');
    var img = container.children[0]; // assuming image is first child
    // var img = container.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; // use this one if not
    if( img.width >= 570 || img.height >= 600) container.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
}
```

It's possible that jQuery is doing some validation on your CSS call and is failing for some reason. Plain JS is more reliable ;)

Comment: Tried your code, working as intended on firefox, but not in Google Chrome. Same Issue.

Comment: That's strange. Try using the Inspector on the element (right-click, Inspect), and check its Inline Styles. You should see `background-size:contain` up there. If it's crossed out, there may be a warning icon that you can move your mouse over to see the reason for it not working.

Comment: There isn't at all that line. I've already checked that prior to ask here. I can see on Computed Styles, that background-size is set to Auto, So isn't applied at all.

Comment: Interesting. Can you try adding `console.log(img.width,img.height)` and seeing what comes out?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the chrome console, since i use always firefox for debugging, But the console it's empty. I did add that line inside the Js function, Is correct? Anyway the function it's correct, by calling manually the function, the background get resized.

Comment: Just found out a really strange thing. If i do a refresh (Right-click, Refresh or pressing F5 /CTRL-F5) the background stay at full size, instead if i Enter the url on the address bar, or navigate to it, the background get resized.

Comment: I select you as Accepted answer because you helped me out to find what was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure the image is actually loaded before getting the image width hand height

```
function scaleImg(){

    var actualImg = $('#img_src_div img'),
        imgH=0,
        imgW=0,
        img = new Image();

    img.src = actualImg[0].src;
    img.onload = function(){
         imgW = img.width;
         imgH = img.height;
        alert(imgW+' x '+imgH);
    }
    if(imgH >= 600 || imgW >= 570){
        $('#img_src_div').css('background-size','contain');
    }
}

scaleImg();
```

Comment: I tried your code. The image height/width are correctly loaded, as i can see the alerts. But it still stay at full size. Also in firefox it is not working.